# Valdaition for user exist or not using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation, mongoose

I'm working on a project in React and ran into a problem that has me stumped.

I want to add new user but want to check if user is present or not I tried to give custom message but still not giving me my custom message.

so here is my code and i am not able to figure out how to give custom message.

if any one have some solution it will be really great if you help me

```
const Employee = require("../models/employeeSchema");

//custom imports
const AppError = require("../helpers/appErrorClass");
const sendErrorMessage = require("../helpers/sendError");
const sendResponse = require("../helpers/sendResponse");

const addEmployees = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let data = req.body;
        let newEmployee = {};
        newEmployee.firstName = data.firstName.trim();
        newEmployee.lastName = data.lastName.trim();
        newEmployee.company = data.company.trim();
        newEmployee.email = data.email.trim();
        newEmployee.contact = data.contact;
        newEmployee.skills = data.skills.split(",").map((skill) => {
            return skill.trim();
        });
        newEmployee.altDescription = data.altDescription.trim();
        newEmployee.hobbies = data.hobbies.split(",").map((hobby) => {
            return hobby.trim();
        });
        newEmployee.socialLinks = [
            {
                gitHub: data.gitHub,
                linkedIn: data.linkedIn,
                website: data.website,
            },
        ];
        newEmployee.imageUrl = req.image;
        let employee = await Employee.find({ email: newEmployee.email });
        if (employee.email === newEmployee.email) {
            return sendErrorMessage(
                new AppError(
                    400,
                    "Unsuccessful",
                    "Email already exist try with another Email id"
                ),
                req,
                res
            );
        } else {
            let data = await Employee.create(newEmployee);
            sendResponse(200, "Employee added Succesfully", data, req, res);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return sendErrorMessage(new AppError(400, "unsuccessful", err), req, res);
    }
};

module.exports.addEmployees = addEmployees;
```

I have no idea why this is happening, if anyone has experienced this I would be grateful.

---

**Edit:**

`console.log(employee)` outputs the following:

```
[{ 
  employeeId: 'c88wgb4ocuw01609613746852',
  contact: 123456789,
  imageUrl: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/altafshaikh/image/upload/v1609613765/qbl7ujyz0wi6cy0xt3rf.jpg',
  skills: [ 'sleep', 'laziness' ],
  altDescription: 'Hello Saurav',
  hobbies: [ 'Nautanki', 'doubtfull' ],
  socialLinks: [ {} ],
  _id: 5ff0c1c5327f300a55f6259a,
  firstName: 'Saurav',
  lastName: 'Upadhyay',
  company: 'Raw',
  email: 'sourav23@gmail.com',
  __v: 0 
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `employee` is an array. You need to access the first element.

```js
if (employee.length && employee[0].email === newEmployee.email) {
            return sendErrorMessage(
                new AppError(
                    400,
                    "Unsuccessful",
                    "Email already exist try with another Email id"
                ),
                req,
                res
            );
        }
```

Since the db query condition is `email`, we can assume that it will return empty array if no matches are found. It also means that the array will be populated only if a match is found. So we can also avoid the unnecessary check of emails being equal. You can do this.

```
if (employee.length) {
  return sendErrorMessage(
                new AppError(
                    400,
                    "Unsuccessful",
                    "Email already exist try with another Email id"
                ),
                req,
                res
            );
}
```